# Why doesn't C List Pop work on first run?

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

Just having some trouble implementing a Pop function for my linked-list in C.

It's quite a weird error in that it does NOT work on the first run.

```
Node * operations = GetOperations(); // Retrieve linked-list of operations
Print(operations);
while (1) {
    if (operations == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    Node * temp = Pop(&operations);
    printf("Node popped is: %s\n", temp->data);
    Print(operations);
    Node * temp2 = Pop(&operations);
    printf("Node2 popped is: %s\n", temp2->data);
    Print(operations);
    // Other code down here... //
    return 1;
}
```

And my code for Pop:

```
Node * Pop (Node ** head) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("Error popping! List is empty.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    Node * temp = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    return temp;
}
```

Code for my Node:

```
typedef struct node {
    char * data;
    struct node * next;
} Node;
```

And when I run the program with GetOperations returning (where `->` represents the next node):

```
Op1->Op2->Op3...
```

I get the following output:

```
Operations: Op1->Op2->Op3
Node popped is: (null)
Operations: Op1->Op2->Op3
Node2 popped is: Op1
Operations: Op2->Op3
```

So as you can see, the first `pop` never works.

Comment: You might want to use a debugger to step though the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: The double quotes after `data` seem unmatched. `printf("Node popped is: %s\n", temp->data");` Do those extra double quotes appear in your code too, or are they a copy paste artefact?

Comment: @verbose Sorry those were some copy/paste artefacts! Joachim, I will try the gdb debugger and hopefully come up with something.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg... Did you notice about his `head` declaration?

Comment: can you show your Print function ? and your Getinformation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used your code with my implementation of GetOperations() and Print(). The code works fine.

```
//Structure to represent node
typedef struct node 
{
    char *data;
    struct node * next;
} Node;

//Pop top value from Linked list
Node * Pop (Node ** head) 
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error popping! List is empty.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    Node * temp = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
return temp;
} 

//Create node and save data
Node *createNode(int i)
{
    char *n=malloc(sizeof(4*sizeof(char)));
    n[0]='O';  n[1]='p'; n[2]=(char)(((int)'0')+i); n[3]='\0';
    Node *temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=n;
    temp->next=NULL;
return temp;
}

//Create a list with data
Node* GetOperations()
{
    int i;
    Node *head=NULL,*current;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         if(head==NULL)
         {
             head=createNode(i+1);
             current=head;
         }
         else
         {
             Node *temp=createNode(i+1);
             current->next=temp;
             current=temp;
         }
    }
return head;
}

//Print the linked list
void Print(Node *ptr)
{
    while(ptr)
    {
         printf("%s",ptr->data);
         ptr=ptr->next;
         if(ptr) printf("->"); 
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Start of program execution
int main()
{
    Node * operations = GetOperations(); // Retrieve linked-list of operations
    Print(operations); // Print list
    if (operations == NULL) return 0;
    Node *temp=NULL;
    temp = Pop(&operations);
    printf("Node popped is: %s\n", temp->data);
    free(temp);  // Free popped data's memory
    Print(operations);
    temp = Pop(&operations);
    printf("Node2 popped is: %s\n", temp->data);
    free(temp);  // Free popped data's memory
    Print(operations);
    // Other code down here... //
return 0;   
}
```

I got this Output:

```
Op1->Op2->Op3->Op4->Op5
Node popped is: Op1    
Op2->Op3->Op4->Op5
Node popped is: Op2
Op3->Op4->Op5
```

Comment: Hi, I too have tried testing this with some simple programs and they all work fine as well. I have no idea what's happening in my code.. `GetOperations()` is definitely fine as I print the output of it and all looks fine. Anywho, I've simply done a `Pop` right after `GetOperations()` and my program can continue :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Travv92  Your Print() clearly says that node pointer(operations) point to the head node but i wonder why your script is not popping in the first call. If you could edit you post with complete implementation code, may be we can check it.

Comment: Hi, I've found the issue :). Silly me had been Pushing and empty node onto the front of the list in a different area of the code! Thanks for your help!